# VS 2019 All menus are gone. Visual Studio 2019 Community

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019 Community.
After closing through the "Task Manager" (Windows).
All menus are gone.

[image]

Comment: Try resetting settings [by starting with the /resetsettings parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/resetsettings-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I rebooted my computer. The menus appeared. At first glance, all the menus seemed to be connected.
While I will work like this.